# Strapi v4 - can't add image to existing entry

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong. The upload works. The image gets added to the media library and cloudinary. But the data does’t get added to the entry.

Here’s my code:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('files', image);
formData.append('ref', 'project');
formData.append('refId', projectId);
formData.append('field', 'image');

const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/upload`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
});
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve it? @quti

Answer (score 0):

what I can tell from the docs is that you might need to change `ref` field value to `api::project.project`

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#upload-files-related-to-an-entry

I hope this helps! I had the same issue and this resolved my issue. Strapi docs aren't the easiest to get around :(